# CakePhp and Google Charts Plugin

Tags: cakephp, charts

Hello i'm using Google Charts Plugin to my CakePHP application.

In my Controller i do:
There are two functions that return two graphs.

```
function statistics() {
    $this->timePerClient();
 $this->timePerProjectChart();  
}
```

FUNCTION timePerProject

```
    function timePerProjectChart() {
        $totalProjeto = $this->timePerProject();
        $tempoTotalGasto = $this->tempoTotalInvestido();

        //Setup data for chart
        $timePerProjectChart = new GoogleChart();
        $timePerProjectChart->type("PieChart");
        $timePerProjectChart->options(array('title' => "Percentagem de Tempo (horas) investido por Projeto"));
        $timePerProjectChart->columns(array(
            //Each column key should correspond to a field in your data array
            'projects' => array(
                'type' => 'string',        
                'label' => 'Projeto'
            ),
            'tempoGasto' => array(
                'type' => 'time',
                'label' => '% horas'
            )
        ));
//You can also use this way to loop through data and creates data rows: 
        foreach ($totalProjeto as $row) {
            $percentagemTempoGasto = ($this->timeToHour($row[0]['tempogasto']) / $tempoTotalGasto[0][0]['tempogasto']) * 100;
            $timePerProjectChart->addRow(array('tempoGasto' => $percentagemTempoGasto, 'projects' => $row['Project']['pname']));
        }
//Set the chart for your view
        $this->set('timePerProjectChart', $timePerProjectChart);

    }
```

In my view (statistics) i do :

```
<div id="chart_div" ><?php $this->GoogleChart->createJsChart($timePerProjectChart); 
 $this->GoogleChart->createJsChart($timePerClientChart);
?></div>
```

but I just can not see a single graph. I tested (individually) each and are functioning. 
I'll wish to put multiple charts on the same view.

Is it possible?

thanks

Comment: Which plugin are you using? Is it this one? https://github.com/segy/GoogleChart That one has no createJSChart method

Comment: i'm using this: https://github.com/scottharwell/cakephp-googlecharts-plugin

Comment: okay, in that case your view code looks good.

Comment: yes, and I already tried to put an 'echo' and it did not work. i dont understand... i dont understand.

Comment: see my updated answer below- the problem lies in your controller- ensure that you have followed the steps below AND also that you have included the GooogleChartHelper in your controller as specified in the documentation

Comment: but I can see the graph. my problem is that I can not view two graphs together (in the same view).

Comment: Ah. I understand your question now. I will look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening in your statistics action in your controller? `$this` is an object.

There are a couple steps required to use the plugin: '

1. Get data. Use a find or other model method to get the data you want.
2. Set up the chart:

   $chart->type("LineChart");

   $chart->options(array('title' => "Recent Scores"));

   $chart->columns(array(
   //Each column key should correspond to a field in your data array
   'event_date' => array(
   //Tells the chart what type of data this is
   'type' => 'string',
   //The chart label for this column
   'label' => 'Date'
   ),
   'score' => array(
   'type' => 'number',
   'label' => 'Score'
   )
   ));
3. Add rows to your chart by looping through data, an example is given below

   foreach($model as $round){
   $chart->addRow($round['Round']);
   }
4. Set the chart for your view- this is the same name that must be then called in `<div id="chart_div"><?php $this->GoogleChart->createJsChart($chart);?></div>` in the view.

   $this->set(compact('chart'));

To display more than one chart in a single view, you need to not just use the default `chart_div` as the id of your div. You need to set two different divs and update the objects accordingly:

set

```
<?php $timePerProjectChart->div('projectChart');?>
<?php $timePerClientChart->div('clientChart');?>


<div id="projectChart"><?php $this->GoogleChart->createJsChart($timePerProjectChart);?></div>

<div id="clientChart"><?php $this->GoogleChart->createJsChart($timePerClientChart);?></div>
```

Comment: doesnt work :/
i used an echo like your code and it doesnt worked

Comment: I'm doing all this.  With the exception : `$this-> set ('timePerSetorChart', $ timePerSetorChart);`. I do not use the `compact`.

if I use the compact and then, in my function `statistics` I call the functions that have the graphics, gives me `Undefined variable: timePerClientChart`

Comment: I have updated my answer to address how to create multiple charts on the same view.

Comment: Please consider accepting this question (clicking the checkmark to the left of it) if you feel I've been helpful. It's necessary because the javascript uses the div id to manipulate the DOM to create the chart, so you need a unique ID for each chart.

Comment: just a question. you know how to change the size of the graph?

Comment: Sure! You can set a height and width in the `options` array along with title: `$chart->options(array('title' => "Recent Scores", 'height' => 300, 'width' => 400));`

Comment: i'm so sorry. but i have another doubt.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16776783/cakephp-google-charts-plugin-and-jshelper

if you can help me... :)

Comment: @swiecki Sorry to bother you but I'm having an issue with this; in my view nothing appears; I check the source of the page and it has all the generated JScript but it's commented out for some reason; do you know why or how to fix this?