# CakePHP, Google Charts Plugin and JsHelper

Tags: cakephp

i wish select an element of dropdownlist (choose a Project) and with JSHELPER (ajax) update the GRAPH that show statistics of this Project.

I can choose the Project and through the 'POST' I can generate the array graph, but i cannot show the GRAPH. I tested without JSHELPER and show my Graph.

MY VIEW CODE:

```
    <b>ESCOLHA O PROJETO: </b> 
    <?php
    echo $this->Form->select('projects', array($projects), array('multiple' => false,
        'class' => 'span2',
        'id' => 'projectsTest'));
    ?>
    </br>

     <div id="chart_div" > 

      </div>


<?php
$this->Js->get('#projectsTest')->event('change', $this->Js->request(array(
            'controller' => 'Registos',
            'action' => 'timePerProjectIssueTypeChart'
                ), array(
            'update' => '#chart_div',
            'async' => true,
            'method' => 'post',
            'dataExpression' => true,
            'data' => $this->Js->serializeForm(array(
                'isForm' => true,
                'inline' => true
            ))
)));
```

?>
MY VIEW TIME_PER_PROJECT_ISSUE_TYPE_CHART

```
<div id="chart_div" > 
<?php

            echo $this->GoogleChart->createJsChart($timePerProjectIssueTypeChart);
            ?>

</div>
```

CONTROLLER

```
 function timePerProjectIssueTypeChart() {
        if (!empty($this->request->data['projects'])) {
            $id_project = $this->request->data['projects'];
            $totalProject = $this->timeSpentPerProjectSpecific(10001, 'Registo.issuetype');
            $timeSpent = $this->totalTimeSpentPerProject(10001);

            //Setup data for chart
            $timePerProjectIssueTypeChart = new GoogleChart();
            $timePerProjectIssueTypeChart->type("PieChart");
            $timePerProjectIssueTypeChart->options(array('title' => "Percentagem de Tempo (horas) investido em cada Tarefa",
                'height' => 300, 'width' => 500));
            $timePerProjectIssueTypeChart->columns(array(
                //Each column key should correspond to a field in your data array
                'issuetype' => array(
                    'type' => 'string',
                    'label' => 'Tipo Tarefa'
                ),
                'tempoGasto' => array(
                    'type' => 'time',
                    'label' => '% horas'
                )
            ));
//You can also use this way to loop through data and creates data rows: 
            foreach ($totalProject as $row) {
                if ($timeSpent[0][0]['tempogasto'] != 0) {
                    $percentagemTempoGasto = ($this->timeToHour($row[0]['tempogasto']) / $timeSpent[0][0]['tempogasto']) * 100;
                } else {
                    $percentagemTempoGasto = 0;
                }
                if (!empty($row['IssueType'])) {
                    $timePerProjectIssueTypeChart->addRow(array('tempoGasto' => $percentagemTempoGasto, 'issuetype' => $row['IssueType']['pname']));
                } else {
                    $timePerProjectIssueTypeChart->addRow(array('tempoGasto' => $percentagemTempoGasto, 'issuetype' => 'Sem tarefa'));
                }
            }
//Set the chart for your view
            $this->set('totalProject', $totalProject);
            $this->set('timeSpent', $timeSpent);
            $this->set(compact('timePerProjectIssueTypeChart'));
        }
    }
```

I do not put the code of the controllers, because individually tested and are working.

Thanks

Comment: Hi!! BR???
Não seria `'controller' => 'RegistRos'` ?
Can be `'controller' => 'RegistRos'`?

Comment: @Igor Martin Portugues :) Registo :D As palavras estão corretas... eu penso que o meu erro seja mesmo em não saber como usar o grafico. Se eu o invocar sem qualquer tipo de JsHelper, ele aparece

Comment: Não entendo muito desse google chart. Você tem que tentar descobrir se o problema está em dar o start na action ou em exibir o gráfico. Tente tirar um debug ou colocar aquele layout padrão do cake para ver o que está retornando da sua action. Se estiver ok, vamos ver se ha algo de errado na exibição

Comment: @Igor Martins o problema está mesmo em exibir o gráfico. isso eu ja testei. Se eu pegar no código da view `TIME_PER_PROJECT_ISSUE_TYPE_CHART` e colocar na view 'principal' (sem o codigo do JS Helper) o gráfico aparece normalmente :)

Comment: Nunca usei o JS helper, acho que ele tem pouca serventia e o mesmo vai ser discontinuado, vou postar uma resposta com ajax normal.

Answer (score 1):

Teste com ajax, sem o JS helper:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $("#projectsTest").change(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: { projects: $('#projectsTest').val()},
                url: 'timePerProjectIssueTypeChart',
                success: funcion() {
                $("chart_div").load('timePerProjectIssueTypeChart');
                }
     })
})
        });
```

E não esqueça de colocar `$this->layout = false` no controller

Comment: Edita sua pergunta e coloca o controller, vai ficar mais fácil

Comment: já está! :D Obrigada pela ajuda.

Comment: Editei a minha resposta baseado no seu controller. Tenta de novo.

Comment: Continua sem funcionar. :/ E o problema continua a ser o mesmo: nao mostra o gráfico apenas...

Comment: mt estranho esse google chart, dificil hein. tenta usar o Highchart, mais tranquilo